# how to make sure not to read a file before finishing the write to it

Tags: c++, c, linux, inotify

When trying to monitor a directory using inotify on Linux, as we know, we get notified as soon as the file gets created (before the other process finish writing to it)

Is there an effective way to make sure that the file is not read before writing to it is complete by the other process?

We could potentially add a delayed read; but as we all know, it is flawed.

For a little bit more clarity on the scenario; the two processes are running as different users; the load expected is about a few hundred files created per second.

Comment: I suppose that you can't just create a named semaphore for each file to ensure only 1 process is using a file at a time?

Comment: Define "finish" ... Unless the process closes the file, is it at all possible to determine whether a process is "done" writing to it, even in principle?

Comment: Do you have control over the programs reading/writing the file, or does this need to work with "any third party program" as well?

Comment: Do you mean process synchronization in basic terms?

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply ... The process that creates file into the monitored directory is a third-party software, which I do not have any control over.

The one that monitors and reads the file; yes, I do have full control on that.

Comment: @Cogwheel; by "finish" I meant that the file is created by the process, written data to it and closed.

Comment: @Beginner or is it the other way around ? It looks like the other question was asked after this one created and answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you're currently monitoring the directory with the `IN_CREATE` (and maybe `IN_OPEN`) flag.  Why not also use the `IN_CLOSE` flag so that you get notified when the file is closed?  From there, it should be easy to keep track of whether something has the file open and you'll know that you don't want to try reading it yet.

Comment: Thanks jamessan; your reply helped me arrive at a solution that seems to work for me.
I now monitor for IN_CREATE and IN_CLOSE; combine them to pick the new arrivals into the directory that I am monitoring! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Create it somewhere else, write to it, close it, then rename it - or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yeah, this is the right way. Or create it under a temporary name and rename when finished.

Comment: Thats only if I have control on the process! Here I dont! Its a third party piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `/proc/<pid>/fd` to see if the file is still opened.  If it is not listed there, you can be sure that the process is no longer using it.

Comment: is there a way to find the fd of the file, which is opened by a foreign process; none that I have heard of. AFAIK, the fd is process specific and only the OS and the process will know of the relation between an fd and file on disk; if at all there is a way, I am pretty sure that will be available only to root.

Comment: @CodeMedic Look at the dir.  The fd is a symbolik link to the file itself, so you don't need to convert fd -> name, all you have to do is use `lstat` to see to which file the link points to.

Comment: eg:  user@box:~# ls -l /proc/1433/fd/0 
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2010-07-16 15:31 /proc/1433/fd/0 -> /dev/null

Comment: that would work only if the two processes are running as the same user. Normally /proc/<PID>/fs/* are user only readable. On top of that we will have scalability issues by having to iterate through the list every second or so. Thanks anyways

Comment: @CodeMedic Well, you didn't specify that, so I suggest you edit your question and add that.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the lsof command can help. It lists all the opened files.
$ man lsof

Comment: the question here is not about doing the copy from shell.