# Pickup directories: How not to pickup files that are still being written?

Tags: python, file-io, batch-processing

I have a Python script that checks on a pickup directory and processes any files that it finds, and then deletes them.

How can I make sure not to pickup a file that is still being written by the process that drops files in that directory?

My test case is pretty simple. I copy-paste 300MB of files into the pickup directory, and frequently the script will grab a file that's still being written. It operates on only the partial file, then delete it. This fires off a file operation error in the OS as the file it was writing to disappeared.

- I've tried acquiring a lock on the file (using the FileLock module) before I open/process/delete it. But that hasn't helped.
- I've considered checking the modification time on the file to avoid anything within X seconds of now. But that seems clunky.

My test is on OSX, but I'm trying to find a solution that will work across the major platforms.

I see a similar question here ([How to check if a file is still being written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758631/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-still-being-written)), but there was no clear solution.

Thank you

Comment: The application which is writing the file should really do it atomically, though I realize you may not have control over this.

Comment: I think to do this reliably either the file needs to be written atomically or you need to communicate with the process doing the writing, either directly or indirectly through the OS.  There's OS-specific solutions like file locks and modification events, but AFAIK nothing cross-platform.  Checking the modification time is probably as good as you're going to get for a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could listen to file modified events ([watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) is cross-platform). The modified event (on OS X at least) isn't fired for each write, it's only fired on close. So when you detect a modified event you can assume all writes are complete.

Of course, if the file is being written in chunks, and being saved after each chunk this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem would be to change the program writing the files to write the files to a temporary file first, and then move that temporary file to the destination when it is done. On most operating systems, when the source and destination are on the same file system, move is atomic.

Comment: I'd like very much to do this, but unfortunately I have no control over that part of the system :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the writing portion, about all you can do is watch the file yourself, and when it stops growing for a certain amount of time, call it good.  I have to use that method myself, and found 40 seconds is safe for my conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Each OS will have a different solution, because file locking mechanisms are not portable.

- On Windows, you can use OS locking.
- On Linux you can have a peek at open files (similarily how lsof does) and if file is open, leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the file before coping it? If the file is still in use, then open() should throw exception.

```
try:
  with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
    pass
  # Copy the file
except IOError:
  # Dont copy
```

Comment: This won't work on all OSes.  Linux and OSX don't require files to be locked when they're open.  Also on Windows you probably want to get a write lock instead of a read lock to be sure no other process is writing to the file (use 'wb' instead of 'rb').